# WindowsPhone | How to interrupt ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: windows-phone-7, threadpool

I'm using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` for do an async task that do `POST` request via `HTTP`.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(UploadPhoto), photoFileName);
```

For now I want to add possibility for a canceling upload from UI.

I have two questions:

- How can I realize thread interruption?
- Is `ThreadPool` suitable for my target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [Task.Factory.StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782519.aspx) to do async work on WP7. You can use [CancellationTokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx) to force a cancellation. This is how I do my async work. To realize an interruption, you can do the following (using Tasks):

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew( ( )=>
{
    // some operation that will be cancelled
    return "some value";
})
.ContinueWith( result =>
{
    if(result.Status == TaskStatus.Cancelled) // you have other options here too
    {
        // handle the cancel
    }
    else
    {
        string val = result.Result; // will be "some value";
    }
});
```

The ContinueWith clause chains another method to occur after the body of the first task completes (one way or another). The parameter 'result' for the ContinueWith method is the Task that the ContinueWith is chained to, and there is a property called Result on the task 'result' that is whatever return value is supplied by the preceding task.